Dataset conversion wide to long
A huge dataset with more than 1000 variables need conversion from wide to long format. Is there any way to do it easily in R without making separate datasets and merging them later?
I tried 'pivot_longer' but could not convert two variables at once.

See the linked post for examples. Try the solutions with your data, if it doesn't work, then please edit your post, provide example data and your codes.
